# Unbroken text in TD won't wrap

Tags: css

I can't get this text to wrap if it isn't broken with a space.

I don't want the overflowing text to be hidden, I need it to wrap to the next line.

With the following styling, the text just extends past the column into the next columns.

```
<td style="border: 1px black solid; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all; width: 300px; max-width: 300px;">
    mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
    </div>
</td>
```

As you can see I've tried a number of things, including adding a `div`.

What else should I be doing that I'm not?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you've provide looks fine: https://jsfiddle.net/to3p4m76/

Comment: Which browser are you experiencing this on?

Comment: Chrome. I'm also using Bootstrap so might be that. I'm going through it now and checking the Bootstrap applied styling.

Comment: Fixed - It was due to other styling being inherited that Chrome wasn't listing in the dev tools. Your fiddle helped a lot though, so thanks :)